# Android + Which layout would you suggest?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm laying out a row for use in a ListView and I need a little help.  The row will look like this:

[image]

Below is what I have so far, the highlight bg is not showing up and the text won't align center (sticks to the top).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/rl0"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="0dp"
  android:layout_margin="0dp"
  android:background="@color/grey">
  <!-- shine -->
  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imgShine"
      android:background="@color/shine"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1" />
    <View
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
    <!-- cal graphic -->
    <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/rl1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:padding="10dp">
      <!-- cal bg -->
      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/cal"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
      <!-- month -->
      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvMonth"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/list_cal_selector" />
      <!-- day -->
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDay"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvMonth"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@drawable/list_cal_selector" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- text and button graphic -->
    <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/rl2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
      <!-- team name -->
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTeam"
        android:textSize="23dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:textColor="@drawable/list_text_selector" />
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTime"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvTeam"
        android:textColor="@drawable/list_text_selector" />
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStation"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvTeam"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvTime"
        android:textColor="@drawable/list_text_selector" />
      <!-- add button -->
      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgAddBtn"
        android:src="@drawable/btn"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="10dp" />
      <!-- divider -->
      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgDivider"
        android:src="@drawable/divider"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imgAddBtn"
        android:cropToPadding="false" />
    </RelativeLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use just one RelativeLayout. It will avoid the use of various Layouts and 
its easier to place componentes on screen.

**edit:** This solution works, but I don't know if it's the best:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"  >

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:background="#dedede"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- 
    ...
     -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yeah, but what about setting the bg highlight to 50% height, don't I still need to use a LinearLayout to do that?   And if so, won't that require a FrameLayout to position it behind any RelativeLayouts, like I've done above?

Comment: Hummm.. You will need 50% of height only in ImageViews?

Comment: Also, can you vertically align a view to another view within the same parent RelativeLayout?  I need something like this attribute, android:layout_alignVertically="@id/view"

Comment: Yeah, we'll need a LinearLayout. See above

Comment: Thanks for posting that!  The funny thing is, i can see the shine in the eclipse preview window, just not when it compiles for either the phone or the emulator.  Long story short, I stuck with what I had and used a shape gradient as the background drawable.

Comment: Eclipse preview doesn't work when using layout_height attribute ¬¬

Answer (score 0):

Look at this tutorials you can choose which layout is best. Every layout has own merits and demerits. Only one that layout is not best in android but in most cases  `Relative layout` easy to use because it has move to easy any where of UI.

just like your matches problems, tutorials

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html

you can see more layout of in developer.android.con. which has to learn more simply way. here some  `Best links` you can see various layouts.

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-relative-layouts/

http://www.learn-android.com/2010/01/05/android-layout-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks for the links!  To get specific, is using a LinearLayout the only way to set 2 views to 50% height (or width)?

Answer (score 0):

[image]Check this out

```
![<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Row 1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Row 2" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Row 3" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:background="#fff"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```